# Get only specific document firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the correct way to obtain the information of only a specific document from Firestore? I'm working with AngularFire.

My structure in firestore:

```
paquetes { --> collection
  F9PGuBNcncjTzKmTgxx1 { --> docID1
    nombre: 'Aspitia' --> field
  },
  MmY55B4vFYus5fFmyM2D { --> docID2
    nombre: 'Aspitia' --> field
  },
}
```

I'm trying the following, but I do not get any data (no error in console)

firebase.service.ts

```
getPaquete() {
    const paquete = this.afs.collection('paquetes' + 'F9PGuBNcncjTzKmTgxx1').valueChanges();
    return paquete;
  }
```

component.ts

```
paquete: any;
constructor(private fs: FirebaseService){}  
ngOnInit() {
  this.paquete = this.fs.getPaquete();
}
```

component.html

```
<p>{{paquete.nombre}}</p>
```

Comment: the ask is too generic.

Comment: What I want is to obtain information only from the document with the ID F9PGuBNcncjTzKmTgxx1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

Service:

```
getPaquete() {
   return this.afs.doc('paquetes/' + 'F9PGuBNcncjTzKmTgxx1').get();
}
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.fs.getPaquete().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res.data())          
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect! I just added `this.paquete = res.data();` to be able to use it and added in the html `*ngIf =" paquete.nombre"` otherwise I get an error that `nombre` is not defined.

Comment: You are welcome.. Would you please upvote and accept my answer?